# resolveip some domain but false?

Tags: mysql, linux, wordpress, localhost, hosts

I want to install mysql.
My command：

```
[root@qinyouyi ~]# service mysqld start
Initializing MySQL database:  Neither host '`qinyouyi`' nor '`localhost`' could be looked up with /usr/bin/resolveip
Please configure the 'hostname' command to return a correct hostname.
If you want to solve this at a later stage, restart this script with the --force option
[FAILED]
```

2.So,I try this:

```
[root@qinyouyi ~]# resolveip www.baidu.com
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So,how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check `/etc/hosts` and look at `127.0.0.1 localhost`. once you set this it should work.

Comment: thanks.But it not work.I do not know why about this.                                                         
[root@qinyouyi ~]# cat /etc/hosts
# 127.0.0.1 localhost,localhost.localdomain
# 119.29.145.148 localhost,localhost.localdomain
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
119.29.145.148 qinyouyi
[root@qinyouyi ~]#

Comment: and,when I use "resolveip" ,It will:[root@qinyouyi ~]# resolveip localhost
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[root@qinyouyi ~]# resolveip
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[root@qinyouyi ~]#

Comment: @Jayqin there shouldn't be any `,` in `/etc/hosts`.  May be unrelated but the delimiter between names should be a space character.